# Read Animated GIF with transparency or alpha channel with LeaveInPlace Disposal Method

Tags: matlab, gif, animated-gif

When I read this GIF and then show it with `imshow(I(:,:,:,2),map);` there are stains on the frame of the gif, I think it may because the GIF disposalMethod. How to deal with it?

[image: intended, animated gif]

```
[I map]=imread('smile.gif');
```

This is what i got.

[image: my result, with stains]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to `imshow` frame 2 of the animated gif with alpha channel.

In here only the first frame of the gif has the full smiley image and the background of smiley contains `TransparentColor`. In rest of the frames some pixels of smiley are also set as `TransparentColor`. So to get the  other frames you have to replace the `TransparentColor` pixels with the pixels from rgb image of previous frame. It is like placing the required frame on top of the previous frames to get the full image.

```
% which frame to show
frame=2;

% filename of gif image
filename='smile.gif';

% Reading gif image
[I map]=imread(filename);

% get information from graphics file( we need the TransparentColor 
% and ColorTable of the gif)
info=imfinfo(filename);

% Set the transparent color to what ever color you like. 
% Because this will be the background color for frame 1 and this
% will be copied to the next frames.
info(1).ColorTable(TransparentColor,:)=[1 1 1];
% RGB Image of first frame
im_new=ind2rgb(I(:,:,:,1),info(1).ColorTable);

% loop from second to the required frame
for frameIndex=2:frame
% get information from graphics file( we need the TransparentColor 
% and ColorTable of the gif)
info=imfinfo(filename);    

% Get the transparentColor of current frame
TransparentColor=info(frameIndex).TransparentColor;

% Change that transparentColor in the map to [NaN NaN NaN]
info(frameIndex).ColorTable(TransparentColor,:)=[NaN NaN NaN];

% Generate rgb image with I and modified color table
imNaN=ind2rgb(I(:,:,:,frameIndex),info(frameIndex).ColorTable);

% We are setting it as [NaN NaN NaN] because then we can find 
% thoses transparent pixels using 'isnan(imNaN)'. 

% Change that transparentColor in the map to [0 0 0] and generate 
% another rgb image
info(frameIndex).ColorTable(TransparentColor,:)=[0 0 0];
im=ind2rgb(I(:,:,:,frameIndex),info(frameIndex).ColorTable);

% 'im' will have [0 0 0] in pixel places of [NaN NaN NaN].
% We are putting zero here because then we can find where there 
% is NaN in 'imNaN' and get those pixels from the previous rgb frame and 
% add thoses with the zero in 'im'.

% copy the previous rgb frame to 'im0'
im0=im_new;

% Now as said before we are going to find the pixels with 
% 'NaN' present using 'isnan(imNaN)' this will be one or zero 
% for each pixel. If the pixel is 'NaN' then 'one' otherwise 'zero'.
% Now we mutiply this with the coresponding pixel in frame one. If the
% pixel is not 'NaN' then the product will zero otherwise pixel 
% value of im0. We add this to 'im'. Which has 'zero' instead of 'NaN'. 
% The result will be, where there is 'NaN', pixel from 'im0' is copied 
% to im_new otherwise 'im_new' will have 'im'.
im_new=((isnan(imNaN).*im0))+im;

% This is repeated till the required frame is reached
end

% show image
imshow(im_new);
```

Since this gif has pixels that are transparent. In here I have used white to fill the transparent part. If you need a different color change `[1 1 1]` in

```
info(1).ColorTable(TransparentColor,:)=[1 1 1];
```

to the required value. Each value varies from `0 to 1`. For which 0 is complete absence of that color component and 1 is complete presence of that color component. For in between colors use decimal values (0.25,0.7,....etc)

Comment: @Fitri I have updated the answer with line by line explanation.

Comment: I have also updated the code as well. Previous code was working for frame 1 & 2 only. I have corrected it and now it will work for all the frames